# B2 visa for transit?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am a Canadian permanent resident and live close to the US/Canadian border. I have noticed that the flights to the US are cheaper and more convenient for me, which is why I want to apply for a US B2 visa. I do not have a Canadian passport, and the US does not allow visa-less entry for my current nationality.
I intend to use the visa mainly to cross over to Canada, and maybe if I feel like it to travel a bit.

Could someone suggest if I should mention my desire to use the visa in order to get cheaper flights on the application (writing duration of stay as less than 24 hours)? Will mentioning this hurt my visa chances?
Or should I strictly stick to the 'applying for tourism' shtick?

Breifly:
Plan to go to Canada from Asia, flights to US are cheaper (and I live close to the border) - hence planning on applying for B2 visa. Will mentioning I plan on staying less than 24 hours on my DS-160 hurt my chances?

Comment: this is a confusing question. Flights to the US from where? Canada? Or you mean flights **from** the US to other places are cheaper than directly from Canada? Then you say you're going to use the US visa to cross over to Canada? From Canada? How often do you intend to use it? Will you get a new one every time you book a cheaper flight from Canada to somewhere through the US?

Comment: @KateGregory Flights from other countries to the US are often cheaper than to places in Canada (or Mexico where I live), so flying from country X to the US, then driving from US to Canada would be a far more economical option if allowed to do so than flying direct to Canada (so B2 visa required).

Comment: but presumably each of these trips has an in part and an out part, right? Does the OP just want to fly **to** Canada, where they live, once? I can't understand the question as written. Most people ask about flying **from** the place they live and then back again.

Comment: @Leobaw When my family got our B2 visas we did so for very similar reasons to yours - ability to travel to/from the US was far cheaper, and also to be able to shop in the US for things cheaper or unavailable where we are (we're in Mexico, not far from the US/Mexico border).  The difference for us is that we are from a visa waiver country (we applied for B2 visas to make border crossings easier) and unfortunately I don't remember what we put for our travel reasons so can't give you an answer.

Comment: @KateGregory For now, yes once. Maybe when travelling again I will do it through the US if I get the visa. My main purpose for getting b2 is cheaper airfare. The question was will this hurt my chances? As I won't be applying for 'tourism' purposes.

Comment: @Midavalo Do you remember if you mentioned on the DS-160 how long your duration in the US would be? 
The lowest possible one is less than 24 hours and you don't have to provide a US address where you will be staying. Other options multiple days/weeks/months require an address. I will be selecting less than 24 hours but feel since it is a visa for tourist purposes, the numbers of hours will say otherwise.

Comment: I have no experience with B1/B2 but Singaporean family who just needed ESTA put "transit" as their reason and got it within half an hour of applying.

Comment: @Leobaw I'm sorry it was in 2017 I just don't remember.  I suspect I would have said something about mostly short stays for shopping, mail, and occasional travel, but I don't know for sure.  I tried to find a copy of my application (it's the kind of thing I would have saved) but just have the confirmation documents and not the application itself

Comment: Have you already applied for (and received and used) visas from the US in the past? It may make sense applying for a transit visa (C) initially, especially as in some consulates (not all) you can get an interview quicker (woohoo! 10 months instead of 2 years in Vancouver, and even down to 3 months in Ottawa and Quebec). But the C visa is strictly reserved for transit. No shopping, visiting, sightseeing…

Comment: "Or should I strictly stick to the 'applying for tourism' shtick?": If you really anticipate never wanting to visit the US "for business or pleasure," why not apply for a C-1 transit visa?  "but feel since it is a visa for tourist purposes, the numbers of hours will say otherwise": lots of people make quick day trips across the border for one reason or another: shopping, visiting a museum, going to a concert or sporting event, etc., etc.  Wanting to have the option of doing this -- or even of visiting for a few weeks -- at some point during the visa's validity is enough to justify a B visa.

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply for the correct visa as per the purpose of your visit. To apply for a B1/B2 visa, the purpose of visit should be business or tourism. If the purpose of travel is to transit the US, then you need to apply for a C1/D visa.

However, if you already have a B1/B2 visa, you can use it to transit. But you shouldn't state transit as primary purpose while applying for it.

So either apply for a C1/D visa, or plan a short trip to the US and use that as a purpose to apply for the B1/B2 visa.

This has been clarified in the fifth question on this page:

https://gy.usembassy.gov/ask-the-consul-april-2022/

(Though this page is on the website of the US embassy in Guyana, I am assuming that the information on this page applies to US visas in general)